# Why should I need a tweak to force VMware ESXi 5 to sync time with Windows NTP server

Tags: vmware-esxi, ntp

I'm plagued by a seemingly simple but actually troublesome problem, so I ask for help here.

#### Symptom

I installed an instance of VMware ESXi 5.1 inside VMware Workstation to learn about various ESXi features. Let me call it vESXi machine. My problem running vESXi is, everytime I suspend the vESXi at night and resume it the next day, the time in vESXi lags. That is, if I suspend vESXi at 22:00 last night and resume it today morning, I will see vESXi reports it is still 22:00 last night. I know this is normal because a PC system keeps its time by counting hardware timer tick interrupt. So, I decide to have vESXi use NTP to sync with an NTP server. My NTP server is a Windows Server 2003 domain controller running on the same LAN segment.

I quickly observe the problem: my vESXi never sync its time with the Window NTP server, no matter how long I wait.

You may suggest that I shutdown vESXi instead of suspend it, but I really love the suspend feature provided by VMware Workstation, which is really quick and fluent.

[image: snap0327-esxi-time-drift.png]

#### Questions

I've read http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1035833 which provides the workaround(some tweak to make it work with Windows NTP server), but that KB article creates more baffles at first reading. What's more, it is really cumbersome to tweak every vESXi if I have quite many of them.

Q1(primary): What on earth does these statements mean?

> By default, an unsynced Windows server chooses a 10-second dispersion
> and adds to the dispersion on each poll interval that it remains in
> sync. An ESXi/ESX host, by default, does not accept any NTP reply with
> a **root dispersion** greater than 1.5 seconds.

Q2: The KB tells me to add

```
tos maxdist 30
```

to **/etc/ntp.conf** . What does that line mean? The ntpd.conf man page http://linux.die.net/man/5/ntp.conf seems to say nothing about `tos` or `maxdist`.

Q3: Since the ESXi NTP client(daemon) does not sync successfully with the assigned NTP server, does ESXi generate some log message explaining the detail?

Q4: Is there any way to force ESXi's ntp client to immediately sync with a specific NTP server? Even a manual operation is welcome. I don't know whether the bundled `ntpd` command can do this.

Q5: Without a manual **/etc/ntp.conf** tweak on ESXi, what kind of NTP server can I set up to provide time source to my vESXi box? Linux ntpd or what? any special configuration on server side required?

Thank you in advance.

#### UPDATE WITH EXPERIMENTS

After reading [NTP FAQ](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-a-faq.htm) and doing quite some experiments, I have confirmed the following facts:

1. With the KB1035833 tweak, the vESXi can really sync with my Windows NTP server, even if the vESXi's time is 7 days behind the server(only a 5-to-10-minute wait).
2. Using viclient to assign a Linux machine(openSUSE 11.4, ntp package 4.2.6 in my case) in my LAN as NTP server, the vESXi without KB1035833 tweak can as well sync with the NTP server with only 5-to-10-minute delay, even with 7-day time lag-behind. But one thing I find I have to keep in mind is that I need to tick **Restart NTP service to apply changes** in viclient in order to force the time sync shortly(in 5 to 10 minutes). In other word, if I don't restart ESXi's NTP service, it will be quite hard to predict how much time it will take to get the time sync after resuming vESXi with an overnight time lag(sometimes it costs one hour or more) -- probably because the resumed NTP client code considers the NTP server time's jitter unacceptable during that period.

So: My practical problem regarding time-keeping for vESXi has been solved(preferring to sync time with a Linux NTP server).

**Now the focus is on Q1.** What's wrong with Windows NTP server? I hope some one can help explain those two statements in Q1 from NTP protocol's perspective.

I express my thanks to quadruplebucky and Reality Extractor for their useful information, although their answers to my specific problem is not quite accurate.

Comment: ESXi is not really _meant_ to be suspended in this way.

Comment: What havoc can it cause then?

Comment: Operating systems which are _designed_ to suspend and resume do a variety of things on resume, such as reinitializing hardware, resynchronizing the clock, etc. If all these aren't done, some hardware and/or OSes (which aren't designed for this) can get into unstable states.

Comment: Your statement is correct by large. But for the case of suspending/resuming vESXi inside VMware Workstation(8.0 or later), the suspend/resume is not performed by OS(ESXi) in the virtual environment, but by VMware's virtual machine manager code. I've never experienced any unstable problem recent years, perhaps VMware Workstation helps us preserve any required hardware state required by the OS in VM. That kind of problems may have happened many years ago, perhaps before VMware Workstation 6.0, year 2006 and earlier. But now I don't think I need to worry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figure it out. The key to understand the VMware KB statements in Q1 is the meaning of **dispersion**. It actually refers to the **Root Dispersion** field in NTP response packet. Windows advertises a Root Dispersion field of around 10 seconds, while Linux ntpd advertises around 0.01 second.

I think Microsoft does this deliberately and announces this behavior in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322/en-us .

The image below shows the 10-second dispersion field(captured with Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If the time difference is too great NTP will not sync.  That's expected behavior.

Normally this is not an issue as the VMware Tools installed in a guest OS will sync the time to the host regardless of how far the time drifted.  Since you are using the experimental and unsupported option to run ESXi as VM you don't get the VMware Tools functionality, and hence it doesn't sync.

For `tos maxdist` you can review [Automatic NTP Configuration Options](http://doc.ntp.org/4.2.4/manyopt.html) but those won't solve your issue because the time is just too far off.

Comment: Thanks. But later experiment reveals that "time difference too great" does not a matter if ESXi use a Linux NTP server. See my update.

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty perverse setup there, ESXi inside VMWare Workstation.  Hats off to you.

NTPD won't make enormous time adjustments like that if it "thinks" it's been running (by, say, being put to sleep).  ESXi, unfortunately, doesn't seem to have a ntpdate binary (which you could just run via cron every half hour or so and disable ntpd entirely).

I have noticed that ntp tends to correct itself if you stop and start the service (maybe a few times).

Ugly workaround, but maybe a cron job to stop/start ntpd?

[Here's a link on adding a cron jobs to ESXi](http://www.jules.fm/Logbook/files/add_cron_job_vmware.html)

The commands to stop and start are

```
/etc/init.d/ntpd stop
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

Comment: Sorry, ntpd service stop then start does not help in this case.